# How to print out a 2D array in MIPS

Tags: mips

This is my code, im just trying to print out the 2D array but I keep getting a bunch of errors or a infinte loop that crashes my IDE. This one compiles but I get runtime error of fetch address not aligned on word boundary. I know Im probably way off and the solution is simple. Assembly just really confuses me Im able to do 2d arrays in java really easliy im unsure where im going wrong please help

```
.data
    array:  .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
            .word 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
            .word 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18
            .word 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24
            .word 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
            .word 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36

    rows:   .word 6
    cols:   .word 6

    newline: .asciiz "\n"
    tab:     .asciiz "\t"

.text
main:
    la $t0, array
    lw $t1, rows
    lw $t2, cols

    li $t3, 0
row_loop:
    li $t4, 0
col_loop:
    mul $t5, $t3, $t2
    add $t6, $t5, $t4
    add $t6, $t6, $t0

    lw $a0, 0($t6)
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, tab
    syscall

    addi $t4, $t4, 1
    blt $t4, $t2, col_loop

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

    addi $t3, $t3, 1
    blt $t3, $t1, row_loop

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

ive tried different types of loops such as while but that resulted in infinte results usually , I dont care if the solution is a while or a iterative loop. I just want to print a 2d array of 6x6

Answer (score 0):

Each item of your matrix occupies 1 word (4 bytes).

So in your inner loop you have to increment your index by 4 instead of 1, and also initialize your `cols` variable to 24 (6 * 4):

```
... your code ...
cols:   .word 24 # instead of 6
... more code ...
addi $t4, $t4, 4 # instead of 1
blt $t4, $t2, col_loop
... your code continues ...
```

Answer (score 0):

gusbro is right, you have to scale somewhere.  And while you can scale your loop counters and loop end points, the more expected way to implement a `for (i=0; i<6;i++)` loop would be to scale during indexing.

Let's start with a C version:

```
for ( int r = 0; r < 6; r++ ) {
    for ( int c = 0; c < 6; c++ ) {
        int *elementAddress = &array[r][c];
        printf ("%p: %d, ", elementAddress, *elementAddress );
    }
    printf ("\n")
}
```

The expression `array[r][c]` has arithmetic and scaling that is hidden in C.  However, with that `printf`, you will be able to see the address of each element, and derive the proper arithmetic to produce the `elementAddress`.

In `array[r][c]`, we need to index `c` columns worth, and `r` rows worth.  Since a row consists of 6 columns, then we need to multiply `r*6` and then add `c`.

Though since each element of the matrix itself occupies 4 bytes, we need the following complete formula for the index: `(r*6 + c) * 4 + array`, where array is the address of the matrix.

Your code

```
mul $t5, $t3, $t2
add $t6, $t5, $t4
add $t6, $t6, $t0
```

is very close but is missing the *4 between the last two instructions, i.e. prior to the addition of the base array address.

```
mul $t5, $t3, $t2
add $t6, $t5, $t4
sll $t6, $t6, 2
add $t6, $t6, $t0
```

Here scaling by 4 is done by shifting left by 2 bit positions.

---

On to optimization.  Since this basically represents a linear traversal of the entire matrix, we can get rid of the address computation by keeping a running address as pointer, by only incrementing that running address by 4 each internal iteration of the loop, here in C:

```
int *runningAddress = array;
for ( int r = 0; r < 6; r++ ) {
    for ( int c = 0; c < 6; c++ ) {
        printf ("%p: %d, ", runningAddress , *runningAddress );
        runningAddress += 1; // 4 in assembly
    }
    printf ("\n")
}
```